# Custom UIGestureRecognizer does not always call its action method

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer

I have a custom UIGestureRecognizer which recognizes the intended gesture correctly (Z-gesture with 2 fingers) and sets `state = .recognized` in `touchesEnded`. The problem is that even though the gesture is recognized, it sometimes calls the action method and sometimes not. This happens undeterministically as far as I can tell.

Does anyone know why?

Here is the code:

```
import UIKit
import UIKit.UIGestureRecognizerSubclass

class ZGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer {

    private var topSwipeStartPoint = CGPoint.zero
    private var diagonalSwipeStartPoint = CGPoint.zero
    private var bottomSwipeStartPoint = CGPoint.zero
    private let minDeltaX: CGFloat = 20
    private let minDeltaY: CGFloat = 20
    private var strokePhase = StrokePhase.notStarted
    var trackedTouch: UITouch?


    enum StrokePhase {
        case notStarted
        case topSwipe
        case diagonalSwipe
        case bottomSwipe
    }


    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent) {
        if !(touches.count == 1 || touches.count == 2) {
            state = .failed
            return
        }

        if trackedTouch == nil {
            trackedTouch = touches.min { $0.location(in: self.view?.window).x < $1.location(in: self.view?.window).x }
            strokePhase = .topSwipe
            topSwipeStartPoint = trackedTouch!.locationInWindow!
        }
    }


    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent) { 
        guard let trackedTouch = trackedTouch,
            trackedTouch.phase != .cancelled,
            trackedTouch.phase != .ended
        else {
           self.state = .failed
           return
        }

        let newPoint = trackedTouch.locationInWindow!
        let previousPoint = trackedTouch.previousLocationInWindow!

        switch strokePhase {
        case .topSwipe:
            if newPoint.x < previousPoint.x { // if we have started moving back to the left
                let deltaX = previousPoint.x - topSwipeStartPoint.x

                if deltaX > minDeltaX && touches.count == 2 {
                   diagonalSwipeStartPoint = previousPoint
                   strokePhase = .diagonalSwipe
                }
                else { // too short right swipe or not 2 touches
                   state = .failed
                   return
                }
             }

        case .diagonalSwipe:
            if newPoint.x > previousPoint.x { // if we have started moving back to the right
                let deltaX = diagonalSwipeStartPoint.x - previousPoint.x
                let deltaY = previousPoint.y - diagonalSwipeStartPoint.y

                if deltaX > minDeltaX && deltaY > minDeltaY && touches.count == 2 {
                   bottomSwipeStartPoint = previousPoint
                   strokePhase = .bottomSwipe
                }
                else { // too short right swipe
                   state = .failed
                   return
                }
             }

        case .bottomSwipe:
            if newPoint.x < previousPoint.x || touches.count != 2 {
               state = .failed
               return
            }

        default: break
        }
    }


   override func touchesCancelled(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent) {
      state = .failed
   }


   override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent) {
      guard strokePhase == .bottomSwipe else {
         state = .failed
         return
      }

      let endPoint = trackedTouch!.locationInWindow!
      let bottomSwipeDeltaX = endPoint.x - bottomSwipeStartPoint.x

      if bottomSwipeDeltaX > minDeltaX {
         state = .recognized
      }
      else {
         state = .failed
      }
   }


   override func reset() {
      strokePhase = .notStarted
      trackedTouch = nil
   }

}
```

As gesture recognition always ends in the line `state = .recognized` when doing the appropriate gesture, I thought that the code was not relevant, but I'll be happy to be wrong.

Comment: I presume there is some code that you have written in this app? Or did you want us to imagine what you had written?

Comment: The problem is that the state gets set to .recognized everytime the gesture is performed, but the action target does not get called everytime, so how is the rest of the code relevant? As I understand it, setting state = .recognized should trigger the target action.

Comment: Are you sure you always reach the code path where `state` is set to `recognized` when you successfully perform the gesture, e.g. by adding a log statement there? Some other things to consider: you never set `state` to the other lifecycle states (`possible`, `began`, `changed`, ...). The docs for subclassing (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uigesturerecognizer#1658520?changes=_4) suggest to always start in the `possible` state.

Comment: Yes I have checked that execution reaches `state = .recognized` everytime when the gesture is successfully performed. If I have understood the docs correctly, the states `began` and `changed` are used with a continuous gesture recognizer---mine is a discrete gesture recognizer. Also according to the docs UIKit sets the state back to `possible` after the gesture has failed or succeeded. A discrete gesture recognizer thus only sets the state to either `failed` or `recognized`.

Comment: I guess the problem is this: `state = .failed` in `touchesMoved` method. This may invalidate your gesture and ignore further action of `touchesEnded` or `touchesCancelled`. Ideally, only `touchesEnded` or `touchesCancelled` should set the state of the gesture.

Comment: `state = .failed` is never executed when the gesture is correctly recognized, so how can it be relevant?

Comment: If I have understood the docs correctly, a gesture recognizer should set `state = .failed` as soon as it has detected that the gesture will fail.

Answer (score 0):

I have simulated your code. I was unable to get the proper gesture (you have not mentioned the gesture required). So, in my case state = .recognized was never executed. Then, I hardcoded the state = .recognized in touchesEnded to check if the action method is called every time state = .recognized is set. I found it to be fine.

What I found out is that all the **overridden methods are missing the super call**. You may put all the super calls and check again. Also, put a log in touches ended. I think there might be a logic issue. As, I do not know the gesture required to trigger it I was unable to debug the code.

Comment: The intended gesture is a Z-gesture with two fingers and it does work correctly. I have not found anywhere in the documentation any mention of having to call super in overridden methods. Even so, I had also tried adding them in but they made no difference.

Comment: As I already mentioned previously: I have checked that `state = .recognized` is reached when performing the gesture. The problem is that sometimes it will not trigger the action method even when execution  reaches `state = .recognized`. In other words the logging message from the `.recognized` branch will print but the logging message from the specified action method will not. And sometimes they will both log a message, meaning that it worked as intended.